# Yii 2 Not Reading a Cookie Set From Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, yii2

Is there a way to get the value of a cookie set by Javascript inside the Yii 2 framework?

Using this code

```
if(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->has('HELLO'))
{
    die("YES COOKIE");
}
else
{
    die("NO COOKIE");
}
```

And I am seeing the HELLO cookie has been set when I inspect. However, the code is returning NO COOKIE.

The cookie was set with Javascript like so

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Comment: How are you making the request? Your `setCookie` function is correct. Some things to consider: Are you making a cross-domain request? Is the cookie set before you make the request? Is the path correct?

Comment: did you disable cookie validation?

Comment: Cookie validation is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cookies you set in javascript won't pass yii validation when you attempt to access them.
the whole purpose of the validation is to ensure that cookies that yii reads and writes are not tampered with.

i dont know your exact use case, but if you need a client action to set cookie data, i'd prefer to set it via an ajax request.
if it's not something sensitive (like getting a tab state or smth), use the $_COOKIE global to access it.
or, the nuclear option, disable cookie validation altogether in application config

docs could help you out [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies#cookie-validation)

Comment: It's not sensitive so I went ahead and used $_COOKIE to read them. Thanks!